# Show that $\phi,\psi$ are diagonalisable and calculate the eigenvalues of $\phi(A)= A^T$ and $\psi(A) = A^T + \sqrt{2}A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

**Task**:
Let $V=\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\phi, \psi \in \operatorname{End}_K(V)$ defined by

\begin{align}
\phi(A)&= A^T \qquad \quad \operatorname{for} A\in V \\
\psi(A) &= A^T + \sqrt{2}A  \quad \operatorname{for}A \in V
\end{align}

Show that $\phi,\psi$ are diagonalisable and calculate the eigenvalues of $\phi$ and $\psi$.

**Question**: Is my attempt valid? How to proceed for $\psi$?

My work so far:

Since $\phi(A)=A^T \Rightarrow \phi(A)^2=A$. So the minimal polynomial is $\mu_A = X^2 - X=X(X-1)$ that can be rewritten as a multiplication of linear factors and thus $\phi$ is diagonalisable.

Comment: I'm assuming you forgot to state conditions on $A$.  These statements aren't necessarily true for arbitrary $A$.

Comment: no information is missing. 
I thought, that applying two time the matrix, that represents the transformation of $phi$ is then the identity mapping. Is that the confusing part to you?

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood the question originally.  I see what you're asking now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt isn't quite right; as a quick check, note that $0$ cannot be an eigenvalue for $\phi$, because that would mean for some matrix $A\neq 0$, $\phi(A)=A^T=0$, but clearly $A=0$ if and only if $A^T=0$. What you have shown is that $\phi^2=I$, as $\phi^2(A)=(A^T)^T=A$ for any matrix $A$. This tells you that the minimal polynomial of $\phi$ divides $x^2-1$.

**Hint for both diagonalizability and eigenvalues:** think about symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices. What happens to these matrices under these maps? Do these matrices span $V$? What does this imply about diagonalizability and the eigenvalues?